# Calculate molecular orbitals of high-lying or Rydberg states in GAMESS (US)

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

I am trying to calculate the high-lying or Rydberg orbitals (i.e. unoccupied orbitals with their energies just below the ionization energy) of a nitrogen molecule.
I use GAMESS(US) with the following input file.

```
!   File created by the GAMESS Input Deck Generator Plugin for Avogadro
 $BASIS GBASIS=N311 NDFUNC=3 NFFUNC=0 NPFUNC=3 DIFFSP=.TRUE. 
 NGAUSS=6 DIFFS=.TRUE. $END 
 $CONTRL SCFTYP=RHF RUNTYP=ENERGY DFTTYP=SLATER MAXIT=99 $END
 $SYSTEM TIMLIM=1440 MWORDS=500 $END

 $DATA 
Title
C1
N     7.0     0.00000     0.00000     0.00000
N     7.0     0.00000     0.00000     1.12001
 $END
```

The output file contains 70 orbitals, but the high-lying orbitals seem to have too big energy.
For example, LUMO+62 has 42.8618 Hartree (or 1166 eV), which is far above the ionization energy of a nitrogen molecule.
How can I correctly get the high-lying or Rydberg orbitals?

Comment: one recommendation I would make is to use a larger basis set. I don't have a formal theory behind this, but I imagine to get a decent description of the $n^{th}$ MO you need significantly more than n MOs. In your case, I would think you might need at least 100 or so. Also, I don't know GAMESS well, but where is the spin set? I know N2 can give some difficulties due to the choice of spin state.

Comment: I found a large basis set called PCseg-4. This basis gives more than 200 MOs. For the spin, the MULT option in the $CONTROL group specifies the spin multiplicity of the electronic state (i.e. singlet or triplet). I use the default setting, which means I only calculate the singlet states.

Comment: There was a Molcas presentation talking about special Rydberg basis sets; I don't know much about that but maybe you need such a BS.